# Create smooth line from zigzag line

Tags: python, shapely, linestring

I've vector which looks something like this
[image: Line 1]
[image: Line 2]

My question is how I can make it smoother/straighter with less points and curves.

Note: I've tried using simplify api from Shapely, but no luck.

Update:
I'm actually creating a given line from polygon (using [CenterLine](https://github.com/fitodic/centerline) python lib), and polygon is created using `rasterio.features.shapes` method which reads [this bitmap](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZWwp6ZizJEVTBzVlEwc2lKeVE/view?usp=sharing).

Code:

```
bin_closing = ... # cleaned bitmap (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxZWwp6ZizJEVTBzVlEwc2lKeVE/view)
results = ({'geometry':s, 'properties': {'id': v}}
               for i, (s, v) in enumerate(shapes(bin_closing.astype(rasterio.uint8), mask=None, connectivity=8, transform=src.transform)))
    geoms = list(results)
    schema= {
      'geometry': 'LineString', 
      'properties': {'id': 'int'}
    }
    with fiona.open('out-bin-closing.shp', 'w', crs=src.crs, driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=schema) as output:
        for i, g in enumerate(geoms):
            poly = shape(g['geometry'])

            # id 1 is actually masked (black part) of bitmap, dont consider it
            if g['properties']['id'] == 1.0 and poly.is_valid:                

                # dont process small polygons
                if len(poly.exterior.coords) < 10:
                    continue

                newline = {}

                # try smoothing polygon
                fx = poly.buffer(50, 2).buffer(-50, 3)

                if fx.is_empty:
                    continue

                # create centerline from smoothen polygon
                geo = Centerline(fx, 10).createCenterline()

                if geo.is_empty:
                    continue                              

                newline['geometry'] = mapping(geo)
                newline['properties'] = {'id': i + 1}
                output.write(newline)
```

Comment: That simplify api is one valid alternative. It seems that you have done something wrong and you must give more details.

Comment: @user30184, I've updated the question

Comment: Add so much code that others can test it. A link to test data would be excellent.

Comment: Please provide the code which does not work, and then we'll be able to help you out.

Comment: added link to bitmap and code

Comment: @user30184 @devdatta-tengshe, One more thing, the line I'm getting is `MultiLineString', I'll try to convert it into single 'LineString', may that can be simplified?

Answer (score 3):

Solved by first applying `shapely.ops.linemerge` and then `simplify`ing it. Patch code follows:

```
...
geo = Centerline(fx, 10).createCenterline()
# make a single line from multilinestring
line = shapely.ops.linemerge(geo)
# simplify
line = line.simplify(5)
...
```

Comment: Would be great if you could [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/231425/edit) this answer to include the final code you used and the image of the result :)

Comment: @Joseph done, kept it to the point, havent copy-pasted code as it is again.